# Cannot Read Property 'subscribe' of Angular Test Mock

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, jasmine, mocking, rxjs

I'm trying to unit test an Angular component that has an injected service. In the component's constructor, a method on the injected service is called that returns an Observable. I'm trying to mock the service in my component's unit test, but I keep running into this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined`.

I've tried to mock the service in the following ways:

```
const serviceStub = {
  getObservable: () => { return {subscribe: () => {}}; },
};

beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
      {provide: MyService, useValue: serviceStub}
    ]
})


it('should create', () => {
  spyOn(serviceStub, 'getObservable').and.returnValue({subscribe: () => {}});
  expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
```

It feels like I'm missing something obvious. Can someone please point it out?

### UPDATE

I get this error even when I inject the actual service in my test bed providers.

The component's constructor looks something like this:

```
private _subscription: Subscription;

constructor(private _service: MyService) {
  this._subscription = _service.getObservable().subscribe(console.log);
}
```

Comment: Did you paste all the code?

Comment: the error indicates that something.subscribe(), the something is undefined. It should have the code line number. Please check it.

Comment: Well, this is Angular, so it's not quite as simple as finding a line number. Here's what I've got for you: `at new ApplicationRef_ (webpack:///~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js:4932:0 <- src/renderer/test.ts:5387:37)`. I realize that the problem is that the "something" is `undefined`. I've explained above what I've done to try to get around that.

Comment: It's from webpack, so it is compilation error? not runtime error?

Comment: The error occurs when I run `ng test`.

Comment: Is _service injected correctly? Can you put log there? To see what is value of _service.getObservable()

Answer (score 8):

Use inject to inject the service and mock it not stub

```
it('should create', inject([MyService], (myService: MyService) => {
  spyOn(myService, 'getObservable').and.returnValue({subscribe: () => {}});
  expect(component).toBeTruthy();
}));
```

Here is full version:

component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-cmp',
  template: 'my cmp {{x}}'
})
export class MyComponent {
  x;

  constructor(private myService: MyService) {
    this.myService.getObservable()
      .subscribe(x => {
        console.log(x);
        this.x = x;
      });
  }
}
```

test:

```
   describe('my component test', () => {
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>, comp: MyComponent, debugElement: DebugElement, element: HTMLElement;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [MyComponent],
        providers: [MyService]
      });
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
      comp = fixture.componentInstance;
      debugElement = fixture.debugElement;
      element = debugElement.nativeElement;
    });

    it('should create', inject([MyService], (myService: MyService) => {
      expect(comp).toBeTruthy();
    }));

    it('should set value', async(inject([MyService], (myService: MyService) => {
      spyOn(myService, 'getObservable').and.returnValue(Observable.of(1));

      fixture.detectChanges();

      fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        expect(comp.x).toEqual(1);
      });
    })));
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Julia! I look forward to trying this out as soon as I get home!

Comment: welcome. let me know. i have a lot of test similar to that

Comment: i updated the answer. it works for me. please try again.

Comment: I appreciate your follow-up, but unfortunately, it's still failing with the same error. I looked at the output a little harder, and it appears that the error is coming from the call to `TestBed.createComponent`, which makes the fact that your suggestions aren't helping make a little more sense, at least...